# RSpec controller test not raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd

I just noticed weird Rspec behaviour. I wonder if it's Rspec's error or my approach to testing is incorrect.

I have this controller test (I cut out unnecessary pieces):

```
describe 'GET #new' do
def get_new(group_id = nil)
  get :new, group_id: group_id
end

context 'with logged in user' do
  context 'with group_id' do
    let(:group) { create(:group) }

    before { get_new(group.to_param)}

    it 'renders correct template' do
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end

    it 'returns success' do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
end
```

this is the way I've been testing controllers for a long time, considering checking against template and response code is enough to make sure controller renders actual page.

However now, tweaking form on the page, I get an error in this action, which I can clearly see in the browser:
[image: browser error]
But I just discovered that both of those tests pass when in fact there is this error.

What am I doing wrong and how do I check for this error in my spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from your view, but by default, controller tests in RSpec won't render views. You can use `rspec-rails`'s [render_views](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views) method to force your controller specs to render views.